Using .NET 8 for ClickOnce - how to detect updates when application is running
I have this .NET 8 clickonce sandbox application (see screenshot).
It reads and prints all the "ClickOnce_*" items from Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().

I publish the application again, and re-read the environment variables by clicking the "[Refresh]" button.
The values do not change. I would like one of the "Version"-variables to change to the newly published version.
So I do not know when I should ask the user to restart the application.
Is there any way to refresh the variables on runtime?
Is there any other way to detect that a new version has been published at runtime?
(When I publish - using the publish wizard - the "Choose when the application should check for updates" is locked on "Before the application starts". I cannot choose "After the application starts").
Am I overlooking something?
